# XIBO client installation on RASPBIAN - RASPBERRY PI 2B

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to install a XIBO client on a Raspberry-pi 2B. I'm using a Raspbian Jessie image (release date: 2016-5-27). 
I've been using [this tutorial](http://rpiserver.breggen.nl/building_xibo.html).

My problem is: When executing "util/build-chromium.sh", I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the answer please: https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/using-a-raspberry-pi-3-for-running-xibo-client/6838/2

Answer (score 1):

> I've been using this tutorial.

The last date I can find on that page is more than two years ago.  This URL:

http://google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src@784

I.e., the repository you are trying to download from, returns a 404.  It no longer exists.  This is why you are getting an "Unable to connect to a repository at URL..." error.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't change the URL in the script since it's constructed by variables. 
I need an uptodate script for util/build-chromium.sh, or eventually a recent tutorial.